# Leftover lines (html/css issue)

Tags: html, css

I don't understand how these lines are being created, yet they appear at the bottom of the page.

[image]

[Source](http://www.whatweekly.com/2015/10/20/conversations-on-theatre-with-ian-gallanar-2/?fb_action_ids=10208030633986485&fb_action_types=og.likes)

The site is running on WordPress, but I still think this is an html/css issue

Comment: What lines?  And please post a screenshot rather than an offsite link.

Comment: It obviously has to do with a bunch of CSS issues. Have you used Firebug?

Comment: [These lines](http://imgur.com/V51MFZL)

Answer (score 0):

These are because of the `pseudo elements` . Following are the selectors:

```
.bottom_social .ssba:before
```

and

```
.bottom_social .addtoany_shortcode > div:after
```

Look out for these CSS selectors and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes `.ssba` and `.bottom_social .addtoany_shortcode > div:after` so due to that those lines are getting created. you can apply below property if those element will not be used anywhere else :

```
.ssba{
display:none;
}
.bottom_social .addtoany_shortcode > div:after{
display:none;
}
```